Issues with extracting icon information
I have an issue with the following code:
#include <Windows.h>

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace::std;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumerateIcons(HMODULE hModule, LPCTSTR type, LPTSTR szName, LONG_PTR ptr) {
    if (ptr == 0)
        return FALSE;

    vector<HICON>* pVec    = (vector<HICON>*)ptr;
    HRSRC          hRes    = FindResource(hModule, szName, type);

    if (hRes == NULL)
        return TRUE;

    DWORD          dwSize  = SizeofResource(hModule, hRes);
    HGLOBAL        hGlobal = LoadResource(hModule, hRes);

    if (hGlobal == NULL)
        return TRUE;

    LPBYTE         bytes = (BYTE*)LockResource(hGlobal);

    HICON          hIcon = CreateIconFromResourceEx(bytes, dwSize, TRUE, 0x00030000,
        0, 0, LR_SHARED);

    if (hIcon)
        pVec->push_back(hIcon);

    return TRUE;
}

VOID IndexIcons(LPCWSTR szFileName) {
    HMODULE Binary = LoadLibraryEx(szFileName, NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE);
    if (!Binary)        
        return;    

    vector<HICON> Icons;
    EnumResourceNames(Binary,
        RT_ICON, (ENUMRESNAMEPROC)EnumerateIcons, (LONG_PTR)&Icons);

    for (HICON hIcon : Icons) {
        ICONINFOEX iconInfo = { sizeof(iconInfo) };
        if (!GetIconInfoExW(
            hIcon,
            &iconInfo))
            continue;
        
        wprintf(L"%s %d\n", iconInfo.szResName, iconInfo.wResID);
    }
}

the console output is nothing, szResName is 0, wResID is also 0, the file exists, ICONINFOEX nor HICON are 0 and the file is there and contains icons. What could be the reason behind those elements of the ICONINFOEX structure being 0 or how can I get them in some other way?

The format of icon resources.

I suggest you could refer to the Blog：Icons and cursors know where they came from
ICO file represents not just one icon but rather a collection of icons (known as an “icon group”). If the icon was loaded by ordinal, then the szResName is an empty string and the ordinal is placed in the wResID member. If the icon was loaded by name, then wResID is zero and szResName contains the resource name.
